# How to allow connections to a socket only within the same host in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server, protocols

I have a use-case where I want to open a socket and allow connections that are coming only from the same host/machine in which the socket is opened. I don't want to allow any connections from other hosts.

Basically, I want to simulate [VM protocol concept of Apache ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/vm-protocol) which works on port 61616.

I want to create something like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000)
```

Is there a way we can do this in Java? Or is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You mean a `ServerSocket`? It has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,java.net.InetAddress)) where you can specify the address you want to accept connection to.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,java.net.InetAddress))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a `ServerSocket` that is bound to `127.0.0.1` for IPv4 or `::1` for IPv6.  Only clients on the localhost will be able to connect to it.